# HTML Class Question. What is '-' in class?

Tags: html, css, class

[image: class]

In this picture, does '-' act in a way that connects between id? or the entire 'fa-facebook' is an id?

Answer (score 1):

The entire fa-facebook is the class. Easier to read than faFacebook.

Answer (score 0):

Hyphens are valid characters in CSS class names, so `fa-facebook` is one single class name.

A lot of libraries (in this case [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/)) use a prefix like this as a [namespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace) mechanism, to prevent clashing with user-defined class names.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/449000/3558960) does a very good job at explaining what constitutes a valid CSS class name.

Answer (score 0):

From the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#classes):

> The attribute, if specified, must have a value that is a set of space-separated tokens representing the various classes that the element belongs to.

So, the `-` is a token part (or class identifier).

Answer (score 0):

```
fa-facebook
```

is a class But you can add your own class to add style or anything.

Basically `fa-facebook` is for any CDN class but If your change as your own style the CDN style may be changed. So it will be good to add new class or Id.

Answer (score 0):

"-" uses to separate the word.It increases the readability of the identifuer by separating the words by hyphen.But that is not a rule , it's a best practice .As per your question , **fa-facebook** is the entire class name (identifier). **faFacebook** or **fa_facebook** are also valid. But if you write it as two words by separating spaces (**fa facebook** , then that identify as two classes.

Answer (score 0):

The **fa-facebook** represents a single class name and **fafacebook** is also a valid class name but the earlier one is easy to read.